# x86 Assembly Sign Flag Not Thrown

Tags: assembly, x86, irvine32

This x86 program displays the correct result of -5 but why isn't the sign flag thrown? I thought it would be 1 since the answer is negative.

```
INCLUDE irvine32.inc

.data
    numA dword 3
    numB dword 2
    numC dword 3
    numD dword 7
.code

main proc


    mov eax,0
    mov ebx,0
    mov ecx,0
    mov edx,0

    mov eax, numA
    mov ebx, numB
    add eax, ebx

    mov ecx, numC
    mov edx, numD
    add ecx, edx

    sub eax, ecx

    call writeint 
    call dumpregs

    exit
main endp
end main
```

Comment: Presumably `writeint` destroyed the sign flag. Swap the two printouts to test.

Comment: @Jester Yeah that was it, thank you.

Comment: You only need 4 instructions for the calculation: `mov eax, numA` / `add eax, numB` / `sub eax, numC` / `sub eax, numD`.  Your way has slightly more instruction-level parallelism, which you could achieve with just 1 more instruction more than what I suggested.  You don't need to zero a register before using it as the destination of a write-only instruction like `mov`.  (Single-step your code with a debugger instead of calling`dumpregs`)

Comment: @PeterCordes So `mov` is actually moving the data from `numA` into `eax` overwriting anything currently there and not just moving the pointer, correct?

Comment: This is MASM syntax (not NASM), so yes it's a load.  Many people consider it good style to write it as `mov eax, [numA]` to make that explicit, vs. `mov eax, OFFSET numA` for the pointer as an immediate.